# Android list widget and item click not working

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I have a home screen widget, a list one, and as usual, I want each item to open the activity when clicked.

I see a lot of answers with toast and broadcasts, but I want it to open an activity. The thing is, the click doesn't work.

Here is what I've done:

The `widget_info.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:previewImage="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical" />
```

The `Provider`

```
class StickyWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        if (ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE == intent.action) {
            updateWidget(context)
        }
    }

    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
        for (i in 0 until appWidgetIds.size) {
            val appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i]

            val rv = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_container)
            rv.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list, Intent(context, MyWidgetService::class.java))

            val activityIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_list, pendingIntent)

            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.widget_list)
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv)
        }
    }

    private fun updateWidget(context: Context) {
        val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(
                appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(
                        ComponentName(context, StickyWidgetProvider::class.java)
                ),
                R.id.widget_list)
    }
}
```

And the `RemoteViewsFactory`

```
class StickyWidgetRemoteViewsFactory(private val context: Context) : RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    private var itemList: List<MyItems>? = null

    private fun updateWidgetListView() {
        itemList = filled by somrthing
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        updateWidgetListView()
    }

    override fun onDataSetChanged() {
        updateWidgetListView()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        itemList = null
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return if (itemList != null)
            itemList!!.size
        else
            0
    }

    override fun getViewAt(position: Int): RemoteViews {
        val remoteView = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_row)
        val item = itemList!![position]

        // fill the view //

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable(MainActivity.EXTRA_ITEM, item)
        val fillInIntent = Intent().putExtras(bundle)
        remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_item, fillInIntent)

        return remoteView
    }

    ...
}
```

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Following the guide https://developer.android.com/guide I have the `setPendingIntentTemplate` in the `Provider`, filled by the `setOnClickFillInIntent` in the factory, but the item click does nothing.

For information the widget is a `LinearLayout` with some `TextViews` which are `android:textIsSelectable="false"`, `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"`.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Change android:clickable="false" to `android:clickable="true"`